# Graph Shortest Paths w/Dynamic Weights (Repeated Dijkstra? Distance Vector Routing Algorithm?) in R / Python / Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, graph, igraph, shortest-path

I have a graph of a road network with avg. traffic speed measures that change throughout the day. Nodes are locations on a road, and edges connect different locations on the same road or intersections between 2 roads. I need an algorithm that solves the shortest *travel time* path between any two nodes given a start time.

Clearly, the graph has dynamic weights, as the travel time for an edge *i* is a function of the speed of traffic at this edge, which depends on how long your path takes to reach edge *i*.

I have implemented Dijkstra's algorithm with
edge weights = (edge_distance / edge_speed_at_start_time)
but this ignores that edge speed changes over time.

My questions are:

1. Is there a heuristic way to use repeated calls to Dijkstra's algorithm to approximate the true solution?
2. I believe the 'Distance Vector Routing Algorithm' is the proper way to solve such a problem. Is there a way to use the Igraph library or another library in R, Python, or Matlab to implement this algorithm?

**EDIT**
I am currently using Igraph in R. The graph is an igraph object. The igraph object was created using the igraph command graph.data.frame(Edges), where Edges looks like this (but with many more rows):

[image]

I also have a matrix of the speed (in MPH) of every edge for each time, which looks like this (except with many more rows and columns):

[image]

Since I want to find shortest *travel time* paths, then the weights for a given edge are edge_distance / edge_speed. But edge_speed changes depending on time (i.e. how long you've already driven on this path).
The graph has 7048 nodes and 7572 edges (so it's pretty sparse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists an exact algorithm that solves this problem! It is called time-dependent Dijkstra (TDD) and runs about as fast as Dijkstra itself.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, neither igraph nor NetworkX have implemented this algorithm so you will have to do some coding yourself.

Luckily, you can implement it yourself! You need to adapt Dijkstra in single place.
In normal Dijkstra you assign the weight as follows:
With `dist` your current distance matrix, `u` the node you are considering and `v` its neighbor.

```
alt = dist[u] + travel_time(u, v)
```

In time-dependent Dijkstra we get the following:

```
current_time = start_time + dist[u]
cost = weight(u, v, current_time)
alt = dist[u] + cost
```

TDD Dijkstra was described by Stuart E. Dreyfus. An appraisal of some shortest-path
algorithms. Operations Research, 17(3):395–412, 1969

Currently, much faster heuristics are already in use. They can be found with the search term: 'Time dependent routing'.

Answer (score 0):

What about igraph package in R? You can try get.shortest.paths or get.all.shortest.paths function.

```r
library(igraph)
?get.all.shortest.paths
get.shortest.paths()
get.all.shortest.paths()# if weights are NULL then it will use Dijkstra.
```

Comment: I'm currently using what you suggest. However, this solution assumes that weights are static (i.e. it always takes 17min to drive from place A and place B). I need a way to use _dynamic_ weights (i.e. it takes 5 mins to travel from place A to place B at 3am when there is no traffic, but 20 mins at 6pm rush hour). The question is, how to solve shortest.paths with dynamic weights?

Comment: @user3580621 in what format do you have your weights? as a time dependent data frame? as some function of time? the structure of your data will inform your approach.

Comment: If your dynamic times are predefined, and also you have used them in preparing your graph, then shortest.path function will use them if you assign NULL for weigths. Therefore, before searching shortest paths you should generate a weighted graph. It depends on your data. If you could prepare a sample and upload it, it would be better to discuss.

Comment: @Gary Weissman & user3079143 -- I just uploaded screenshots of the data structures (seems to be the easiest way, since no latex compatibility here). Let me know if you'd prefer actual sample data files.

Comment: I think you should consider each time during a day in a independent graph. Then if you have data for 5 separate times during a day, then you can have 5 independant graphs

Comment: Or much better, you can merge distance and speed and achieve a single weight (20km is the distance and speed is 60km/hr, then it will take 20 min to reach from A to B. Thus, 20 can be new weight.

Comment: @user3079143 What you describe is what I'm currently doing. However, the speed might be 60km/hr when you start driving. But after 5 minutes, traffic increases and you're going 55km/hr...then after another 5 minutes you're going 50km/hr...meanwhile, alternative routes may have _decreasing_ traffic (increasing speeds). This means that solving the problem this way finds the wrong solution, as it fails to take dynamic edge weights into account.

Comment: @user3580621 Have you ever checked ODE? Its for dynamic formulations based of differential equations. Just imagine it as a biological reactions. There are a chain of reactions which each of them has special characteristics. Then you can calculate the output of several chains dynamically. check this for example :http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042706002159

Answer (score 0):

def dijkstra(G, src):
distances = {node: float('inf') for node in G.nodes()}
distances[src] = 0

```
pq = [(0, src)]
while pq:
    current_distance, current_node = heapq.heappop(pq)

    if current_distance > distances[current_node]:
        continue

    for neighbor in G.neighbors(current_node):
        weight = G.edges[current_node, neighbor]['weight']
        distance = current_distance + weight
        if distance < distances[neighbor]:
            distances[neighbor] = distance
            heapq.heappush(pq, (distance, neighbor))

return distances
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).